# Vertical alignment issues

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am doing a event list and i would like make it in the middle. However, it's failed many times, i have tried to put `vertical-align: middle` almost everywhere and still not working.

I tried also to put in the html itself instead of my css file and i do not want to use something like padding or margin cause it will affected a lot of elements

[image: the list]

```
<div id="programlist" class="bounce-in">
  <div12>
      <li1 style="width: 15%;"><img src="images/icon/idea.png" width="100px"></li1>
        <li1 style="width: 50%;"><h3>ABC EVENT</h3><p>You can xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx.</p></li1>
        <li1 style="width: 5%;"><img src="images/time.png" width="50px" height="50px"></li1>
        <li1 style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle"><p><strong>12/2/2019</strong></p></li1>   
        <li1 style="width: 20%;"><a onclick="window.open('idea/index.html','popUpWindow','height=800,width=1160,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');"><buttonclass="button"><span>REGISTER</span></button></a></li1>    
    </div12>
</div>

<style>
  #programlist div12 {
    display:flex;  
    list-style:none;
    height: 130px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  }

  #programlist div12:hover {
    background: #eee;
  }


  #programlist h9 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
  }

  #programlist li1 img {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
  }


  #programlist li1 {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #programlist button {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #00645a;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  #programlist button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  #programlist button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  #programlist button:hover span {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }

  #programlist button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
```

How can I make my list vertically aligned centred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://codepen.io/crocsx-the-styleful/pen/jdByeq

use

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

on your li